# Is it possible to integrate Bamboo and Jenkins with TestRail

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, jenkins

My company is currently using Bamboo and Jenkins for our build CI (depending on project) and we're moving into using TestRail for our test case management as Zephyr wasn't providing the necessary level of functionality.

Is it possible to directly integrate Bamboo and Jenkins into TestRail so that our build tests, etc run and automatically update TestRail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestRail has a very simple API that you can use to push test run results.  In my company we are switching from Jenkins to Bamboo.  Our automation tests are written with RobotFramework.  All our tests use RobotFramework Tags to map the TestRailID to the test.  After an execution, we have a script that pushes the results of the test run from RF to TestRail using TestRail's API.  We also have a Bamboo job that executes the tests daily on  set schedules and can push those results to TestRail as well.

Comment: can you please share how did you integrate your robot tests with bamboo and how the execution was triggered

Comment: pgtips - commenting because of MD5's comment that was an answer but was deleted for not being an answer :)